# Не открывается браузер по умолчанию

Tags: c#

При попытке открыть браузер при помощи

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

Кидает исключение

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "Не удается найти указанный файл"

Comment: Попробуй октрыть ссылку сохраненную в ярлык. Как себя поведет операционная система?

Comment: Какая у Вас операционная система? Ваш код работает у меня на Win7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попросите проводник Windows (explorer.exe)  сделать, то что вам нужно

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Это будет не дефолтный браузер. В вопросе спрашивается именно про браузер по умолчанию. Окроме того не сработает на операционных системах, где IE не стоит (например, WIN10 LTSB/LTSC)

Comment: Andrew, Вы попробовали? Данная команда открывает дефолтный браузер.

Comment: @Andrew explorer.exe - это проводник Windows. Internet Explorer это iexplore.exe

Comment: Как бы это не казалось странным, но это работает. В .NET 5 выбрасывается такая-же ошибка. [Обсуждение проблемы на GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28005). Обходной вариант (кроссплатформенный): `Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = web_link, UseShellExecute = true } );`.

Answer (score 0):

Майкрософт [утверждает](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305703/how-to-start-the-default-internet-browser-programmatically-by-using-vi), что следует вызывать браузер по умолчанию так:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

Я так и делаю обычно (редко пишу на c# и только для windows)

но, если нужна кросс-платформенность, можно идти так (взято [отсюда](https://brockallen.com/2016/09/24/process-start-for-urls-on-net-core/)):

```
public static void OpenBrowser(string url)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(url);
    }
    catch
    {
        // hack because of this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10361
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            url = url.Replace("&", "^&");
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            Process.Start("open", url);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так автор так и вызывает же. Другое дело, что по указанной вами ссылке идёт перехват исключения, которое выбрасывается у автора. Но это мало ему поможет.